# Why does the transform method of the custom pipe fire so many times in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ngfor, angular-pipe

Why does the transform method of the custom pipe fire as many times as it does when used inside this angular2 loop? I expect it to fire only twice.

Many thanks!

[Result in the browser's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmQ8U.jpg)

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyPipe} from './my.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  pipes: [MyPipe],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let country of countries">
      {{ country | myPipe }}
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

  public countries: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.countries.push('Spain');
    this.countries.push('Italy');
  }
}
```

**my.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})

export class MyPipe {
  constructor() {
    console.log('MyPipe');
  }

  transform(param: any) {
    console.log(param);
    return param;
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: Because it evaluates value of view binding each time when change detection runs.

Comment: @PankajParkar Thank you for your response! I still am confused, as I am still quite new to Angular2. 

What is causing 'change detection' to run this many times? I get this after the page has loaded. There are no other changes that I am making.

Comment: I just created a plunker demo, and I don't get the same results. 

https://plnkr.co/edit/QvWKU7URLmKTqzggl7Cg?p=preview

Comment: In your application which version you're using?

Comment: angular2@2.0.0-beta.17, typescript@1.8.10

Comment: That was beta version, try upgrading current version, which is `.rc5`

Comment: I will give that a go and update. Thanks @PankajParkar, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Problem solved. I wouldn't have thought that that would have been the issue, so thanks again for your guidance @PankajParkar!